# Постановка запятой перед союзом "и"

Tags: запятая

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед союзом И: "Ему снилось, что весь город охватил пожар, всюду слышались крики, взрывы. А потом всё пропало, и наступила тишина"

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от смысла, который вкладывает автор.

А потом всё пропало и наступила тишина."Потом" относится и к первому, и ко второму предложению.По-моему, этот вариант предпочтителен.

А потом всё пропало, и наступила тишина.-"Потом" относится только к первому предложению.

Comment: На мой взгляд, предпочтительнее второй вариант. Потому что сначала все пропало, а потом уже наступила тишина.

Comment: Вот видите, каждый свой смысл вкладывает, и всё можно объяснить: всё произошло потом - потом всё исчезло(пожар,крики, взрывы),и потом же наступила тишина, одновременно с тем, как всё исчезло.как хочу, так и ставлю. Если, конечно, это не домашнее упражнение на пунктуацию, здесь придётся поднатужиться, понять, что хотел сказать автор.

Comment: "...пропало. Наступила тишина". Точка равносильна сумме: "запятая" + "и". Значит, запятая легитимна в этом предложении.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы. Т.е. постановка запятой не будет являться ошибкой, как и отсутствие запятой? Можно ли назвать эту запятую авторским знаком? Или как называются те случаи, когда запятую можно ставить, а можно и не ставить. ошибки не будет.

Comment: Нет, это не авторская запятая, а факультативная(на выбор в зависимости от смысла)

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: Не вижу разницы между факультативным и авторским знаком.  В любом случае  все знаки пунктуации  выбираются  (или не выбираются) в соответствие со СМЫСЛОМ, который  хочет выразить автор,  отличаются  же они следующим образом.  Основные знаки препинания  ОДНОЗНАЧНО соответствуют  данному предложению и поэтому выбираются по правилам,  а авторские (факультативные) знаки  меняют   структуру предложения, вследствие чего мы имеем  ВАРИАНТЫ, различающиеся  как по форме (грамматике и интонации), так и по содержанию.

Comment: То, что Вы не видите разницы, не говорит о том, что её нет.Такая тема есть даже в современных учебниках.Общее понятие факультативности в употреблении знаков препинания допускает выделение трех случаев: 
1) знак собственно факультативный – по схеме «знак – нуль знака» (ставить или не ставить) ; 2) знак альтернативный – по схеме «или – или» (взаимоисключение знаков) ; 3) знак вариативный – по схеме «знак на выбор» (параллельное употребление знаков) . Авторский знак - без правил, иногда вопреки им.

Comment: Цветаева: 
Июльский ветер мне метёт – путь, 
И где-то музыка в окне – чуть. 
Ах, нынче ветру до зари – дуть 
Сквозь стенки тонкие груди – в грудь. 
Есть чёрный тополь, и в окне – свет, 
И звон на башне, и в руке – цвет, 
И шаг вот этот – никому – вслед, 
И тень вот эта, а меня – нет. 
Блок: 
…Скалит зубы – волк голодный — 
Хвост поджал – не отстаёт — 
Пёс холодный – пёс безродный…
Вот это - авторские.

Comment: Я думаю, разговор о различии знаков, нужно начинать с определения этих знаков (хотелось бы именно это услышать). По вашему предыдущему высказыванию, факультативный знак зависит от смысла, а авторский со смыслом никак не связан? Назовите принципиальную разницу между ними.

Comment: А возможно ли такое написание: "А потом все пропало - и наступила тишина"?

Comment: Да, возможно, это тема тире как неосновного знака препинания в ССП. Тире можно иметь значение присоединения и соответствовать увеличенной паузе, например: "Я тронул их – и горестно в тиши раздался звук".  "Стали искать черкесов во всех кустах – и, разумеется, ничего не нашли". И в качестве доп. информации:Тире в ССП ставится при наличии следующих факторов: а) быстрая смена событий,б) противопоставление,в) присоединение; г) разная структура предложений и наличие назывных предложений. Обычно тире ставится перед союзами И (присоединение) и союзами И, А, НО (противопоставление).

Answer (score 1):

Смысл предложения "А потом всё пропало, и наступила тишина" не совсем ясен.  Снится ли герою продолжение сна, что он видит и слышит? Речь шла о взрывах и пожарах - это слуховое и зрительное восприятие, а наступила только тишина.

Соответственно,  при неточности содержании сложно говорить о правильности постановки запятой.

Comment: "А потом все пропало" - имеется ввиду, что пропали кадры пожаров, взрывающихся снарядов, пропали все звуки. А "наступила тишина" = "наступили умиротворение, покой". Т.е. человека больше не мучили кошмары, все затихло в нем. Извините, если изъяснила путано.

Comment: В этом случае запятая не нужна, но "тишина" тогда будет нести дополнительную смысловую нагрузку. Отсутствие запятой как раз и подчеркнет этот особый смысл.

Comment: А мне почему-то казалось, что наоборот, что для того, чтобы оградить слово "тишина" от предыдущих слов и нужна запятая. Т.е. смысл должен быть примерно следующим: "Ему снились взрывы, пожары, крики, а потом всё это пропало. И наступила тишина, умиротворение". А выходит, что как раз-таки запятую и не следует ставить, чтобы смысл был таким (как я написала выше)?

Comment: Правила позволяют нам выбрать любой вариант в качестве авторского решения. В этом случае хорошей подсказкой может стать интонация. Возможно, вы правы и с помощью запятой следует обозначить паузу в течении событий. Пишите так, как вы прочитали бы текст. Это будет самым лучшим решением.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, поставлю. Спасибо, что помогали мне!

Comment: Лучше  тире  поставьте.

Comment: Хорошая идея с тире. Спасибо! Но в данном случае как постановка тире будет объясняться? Какое правило?

Comment: "А потом все пропало - и наступила тишина"- вот это как раз авторский: автор придаёт особый смысл последнему сообщению,смысл следствия. По правилам здесь нужно или не нужно ставить запятую,а тире - особый смысл следствия, как в бессоюзном.

Comment: По правилам тире здесь - неосновной знак препинания, его постановка регулируется правилами в соответствии с определенными факторами (резкий переход, разная структура и др.).

Answer (score 0):

Запятую не ставим, т.к. есть  общий второстепенный член - "потом".